# Webrtc in Vuzix m300

Tags: android, webrtc, vuzix

I finished every configuration and tested on multiple Android devices, everything works fine, but when I test the streaming with the Vuzix M300, which is a smart glass run on Android 6, the streaming didn't happen and not even getting any error in Android Studio.Kindly help me out I am new in Vuzix m300.

Below is the java code:

```html
package fr.pchab.androidrtc;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer;
import org.webrtc.VideoRendererGui;
import fr.pchab.webrtcclient.WebRtcClient;
import fr.pchab.webrtcclient.PeerConnectionParameters;

import java.util.List;

import static android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS;
import static android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;


public class RtcActivity extends Activity implements WebRtcClient.RtcListener {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private final static int VIDEO_CALL_SENT = 666;
    private static final String VIDEO_CODEC_VP9 = "VP9";
    private static final String AUDIO_CODEC_OPUS = "opus";
    // Local preview screen position before call is connected.
    private static final int LOCAL_X_CONNECTING = 0;
    private static final int LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING = 0;
    private static final int LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING = 100;
    private static final int LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING = 100;
    // Local preview screen position after call is connected.
    private static final int LOCAL_X_CONNECTED = 72;
    private static final int LOCAL_Y_CONNECTED = 72;
    private static final int LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTED = 25;
    private static final int LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTED = 25;
    // Remote video screen position
    private static final int REMOTE_X = 0;
    private static final int REMOTE_Y = 0;
    private static final int REMOTE_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int REMOTE_HEIGHT = 100;
    private VideoRendererGui.ScalingType scalingType = VideoRendererGui.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL;
    private GLSurfaceView vsv;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks remoteRender;
    private WebRtcClient client;
    private String mSocketAddress;
    private String callerId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().addFlags(
                    LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                            | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                            | LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            requestPermission();
            mSocketAddress = "http://" + getResources().getString(R.string.host);
            mSocketAddress += (":" + getResources().getString(R.string.port) + "/");

            vsv = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glview_call);
            vsv.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
            vsv.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            VideoRendererGui.setView(vsv, new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    init();
                }
            });

            // local and remote render
            remoteRender = VideoRendererGui.create(
                    REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,
                    REMOTE_WIDTH, REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType, false);
            localRender = VideoRendererGui.create(
                    LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING,
                    LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING, scalingType, true);

            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
                final List<String> segments = intent.getData().getPathSegments();
                callerId = segments.get(0);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("error in opening activity"+e);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        Point displaySize = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
        PeerConnectionParameters params = new PeerConnectionParameters(
                true, false, displaySize.x, displaySize.y, 30, 1, VIDEO_CODEC_VP9, true, 1, AUDIO_CODEC_OPUS, true);

        client = new WebRtcClient(this, mSocketAddress, params, VideoRendererGui.getEGLContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        vsv.onPause();
        if(client != null) {
            client.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        vsv.onResume();
        if(client != null) {
            client.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(client != null) {
            client.onDestroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallReady(String callId) {
        if (callerId != null) {
            try {
                answer(callerId);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //call(callId);
            startCam();
        }
    }

    public void answer(String callerId) throws JSONException {
        client.sendMessage(callerId, "init", null);
        startCam();
    }

    public void call(String callId) {
        Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mSocketAddress + callId);
        msg.setType("text/plain");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(msg, "Call someone :"), VIDEO_CALL_SENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VIDEO_CALL_SENT) {
            startCam();
        }
    }

    public void startCam() {
        // Camera settings
        client.start("android_test");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(final String newStatus) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalStream(MediaStream localStream) {
        localStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localRender));
        VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING,
                LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING,
                scalingType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint) {
        remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));
        VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender,
                REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,
                REMOTE_WIDTH, REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType);
        VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                LOCAL_X_CONNECTED, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTED,
                LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTED, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTED,
                scalingType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveRemoteStream(int endPoint) {
        VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING,
                LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING,
                scalingType);
    }
    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), RECORD_AUDIO);
        int result3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result4 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WAKE_LOCK);

        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, CAMERA,RECORD_AUDIO,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WAKE_LOCK}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean locationAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (locationAccepted && cameraAccepted) {
                        //Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {

                        //Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Denied, You cannot access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, CAMERA},
                                                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                return;
                            }
                        }*/

                    }
                }


                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we have just fixed a similar problem.

you may try by adjusting the bolded number parameter a little bit lower.

```
    PeerConnectionParameters params = new PeerConnectionParameters(
            true, false, displaySize.x, displaySize.y, **30**, 1, VIDEO_CODEC_VP9, true, 1, AUDIO_CODEC_OPUS, true);
```

At least, this helps our case.. Hope work out for you too.